# df.drop_duplicates is dropping too many entries

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I am using Python 3.6 to read in a .csv file from BoardEX. I know there is a lot of duplicate entries in the data.

```
main = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/theca/Downloads/579b97d48dc72c8e.csv", encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

main.head()
```

[image]

I need to subset by "BoardID"

```
main["BoardID"].nunique()

191
```

This is good, I think.

The size of the data set is 300 by 6.

But when I do this:

```
main.drop_duplicates(subset ="BoardID", 
                     keep = False, inplace = True)
```

The result is something different?

```
main.shape
(101, 6)
```

Why is the `nunique` number 191, but the number after`drop_duplicates` is 101?

Then maybe someone could kindly tell me how to subset by the 191 value and not the 101 value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if use parameter `keep = False`:

```
main = pd.DataFrame({'BoardID':[1,1,2,3,4,4,4],
                     'Revenue':[4,1,2,5,4,5,7]})

main.drop_duplicates(subset ="BoardID", 
                     keep = False, inplace = True)
print (main)
   BoardID  Revenue
2        2        2
3        3        5
```

it remove only duplicated values, unique rows are not omited.

For same length need `keep = 'first'` for first unique and duplicated values:

```
main.drop_duplicates(subset ="BoardID", 
                     keep = 'first', inplace = True)
```

what is same like omitted, because default parameter:

```
main = pd.DataFrame({'BoardID':[1,1,2,3,4,4,4],
                     'Revenue':[4,1,2,5,4,5,7]})

main.drop_duplicates(subset ="BoardID", inplace = True)
print (main)
   BoardID  Revenue
0        1        4
2        2        2
3        3        5
4        4        4
```